# Incorrect margins on NSOutlineView SourceList view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

A problem that has vexed me ever since Lion was released is the margin/indent on row items of the preformatted NSOutlineView view-based "SourceList" control. Despite all of my best attempts to correct the margins, Apple's built-in formatting takes over and positions the views regardless of what I've specified (whether through the indentation setting or manually moving views).

Here's a picture to demonstrate:

[image]

How might I be able to fix this without resorting to doing everything manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass NSOutlineView and override `-frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:` and `frameOfCellAtColumn:row:` to adjust the disclosure triangle, and text and images respectively.  Call through to super for the actual cell's frame and assign the x-origin of the cell 3 pixels farther to the right in both cases.